# Cannot connect to MongoDB in rocket.rs

Tags: mongodb, rust, rust-rocket

I am using rocket.rs and trying to connect to my MongoDB database which is listed compatible in the docs https://rocket.rs/v0.4/guide/state/#databases

```
[global.databases]
mongodb_logs = { url = "mongodb://Username:password@cluster0-shard-00-00.vegb1.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01.vegb1.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02.vegb1.mongodb.net:27017/myFirstDatabase?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority" }
```

This is how my `Rocket.toml` file looks as it was complaining about the URL should start from `mongodb://` I am using the previous version of connection but it throws this error.

```
 Configured for development.
    => address: localhost
    => port: 8000
    => log: normal
    => workers: 12
    => secret key: generated
    => limits: forms = 32KiB
    => keep-alive: 5s
    => read timeout: 5s
    => write timeout: 5s
    => tls: disabled
    => [extra] databases: { mongodb_logs = { url = "mongodb://username:password@cluster0-shard-00-00.vegb1.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01.vegb1.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02.vegb1.mongodb.net:27017/myFirstDatabase?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority" } }
  Mounting /:
    => GET / (index)
    => POST /new/message application/json (new_message)
Error: Failed to initialize pool for 'mongodb_logs'
    => Error: PoolError(Error(None))
Error: Rocket failed to launch due to failing fairings:
    => 'mongodb_logs' Database Pool
thread 'main' panicked at 'launch fairing failure', /workspace/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/rocket-0.4.7/src/error.rs:214:17
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

When trying the latest version whose URL starts with `mongodb+srv://` and removing the +srv in it I get the same error so I don't really know what's this about but any help would be helpful.

Comment: `PoolError(Error(None))` this would be considered by a bug by my standard you should report this to dev of rocket

Comment: Alright then I guess